# OpenCL: permission (capability) needed to run `clinfo` as non-root

Tags: linux, opencl, intel

I'm trying to move away from running an application using OpenCL (on an Intel GPU, using beignet) as root all the time.  I seem to have run into some permission issue though.  `clinfo` seems to show the same permission issue.  Is there some easy way of finding out what permissions/capabilities are needed?

When I run `clinfo` from the Linux console as an ordinary user I get the following:

```
drm_intel_gem_bo_context_exec() failed: Invalid argument
/dev/dri/card0 not authenticated
Device open failed, aborting...
error in /home/magnus/lcam-deb/libbeignet-lcam/src/cl_api.c line 298
Invalid device
```

As `root` it works fine.

If I start X as the same user and then run `clinfo` in an xterminal it works just fine too.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm having a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the solution was passing `drm.rnodes=1` to the kernel at boot.  I found that information hidden in the *How to run* section on the [beignet wiki](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/).